# Is it usually possible to saddle stitch A4 landscape?

Tags: print-design, binding

I'm only a newbie and I can see lots of A4 portrait saddle stitched print options and A5 landscape, but not A4 landscape. Just wondered if it wasn't possible for most printers for some reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the size of papers available. There are more cheap print shops/copy shops with capability for smaller paper sizes because there is more demand for it. So if your printer prints on A3 medium then it can be folded into a portrait A4, if cut in half its a landscape A5. Many office level printers can do this but printing on bigger papers require different gear that is not nearly as commonly available in copy shops on the cheap.

For a real digital print isn't not really an issue. However, some cut configurations (called [signatures](http://www.designersinsights.com/designer-resources/understanding-and-working-with-print)) offer more bang for the buck. And setting up a different pipeline may also cost you extra. So printers are less inclined to tell you the prices of such jobs, even tough they could provide you with other options. As always, ask the printer.

Comment: @Jenny  ALSO: Paper buyers always try to use standard paper sizes which can be used without waste. Odd-size pages can be wasteful and costly if the quantity is not large enough, or if there is not enough time to order a special making-size of paper stock.